# Android, can no longer import external dependencies after gradle update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just updated gradle for my android project from 2.3.3 to 3.1.3 and now it seems that my project can now longer import dependencies that come from an external source like de.hdodenhof:circleimageview and id.zelory:compressor. Only dependencies that start with 'com' or 'java' work.

[image]

I already tried to clean/rebuild the project and check invalidate chaches/restart.

Sidenote: I also upgraded my other packages to their latest versions, but I think it is a gradle problem.

Another Sidenote: the missing dependencies can also not be found in the external libraries.

Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
       jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module gradle (picture of the changes because the gradle file does not paste well in stack overflow code sample):

[image]

Comment: I have a great number of dependencies missing!  Incredible waste of time

Comment: I recently found out that to get the dependencies back, you have to remove it from the gradle, then sync the gradle, then add the dependency again in the gradle and sync the gradle again. This should be done for all the missing dependencies

Comment: Thank you @2hTu2 !  I had tried every combination of disable Instant Run, opt in/out of D8 Desugaring, Incremental Desugaring, Configuration on Demand, Invalidate Caches, Delete transforms from .gradle folder, clean build.  This happens every time they touch the toolchain.  :(

Comment: Oddly enough everything works when I remove the dependencies.  When I replace the dependencies everything breaks again.